# Clearing a jpanel to transparent

Tags: java, swing, transparency

So, I have a JPanel where I draw a triangle. My intent is to turn the triangle to arbitrary angles that the user chooses. Now in order to be able to rotate the triangle without having it looking cropped I need a JPanel bigger than the triangle. So to achieve all this, my paintcomponent looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Path2D p = new Path2D.Float();
    p.moveTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() / 4);
    p.lineTo(getWidth()-(getWidth() / 4), getHeight() / 2);
    p.lineTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight()-(getHeight() / 4));
    p.closePath();

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);


    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.fill(p);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

It works, but not how I would like it. Right now, it paints a green triangle over a transparent JPanel. The issue is that I want to keep the transparency on the JPanes when rotating the triangle. I know that I'm supposed to clear the contents of the JPanel if I want to redraw the JPanel and not end up with the old and new content, but all the responses I've seen ask to use `clearRect` which doesn't work here. `clearRect` will paint with the background color making the JPanel opaque. Can't I reinitialize the graphics component and draw again?

Right now, trying to set the background with something like

```
g2d.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
g2d.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Ends up just making a black background and the thing that seems more promising is maybe something like:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f));
```

But I don't know how to use the composite options and I keep making the triangle transparent and not the background

This should create the version with the `clearRect()` and the black background:
package clicknturn;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ClickNTurn  extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClickNTurn ex = new ClickNTurn();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public ClickNTurn() {

       setTitle("Simple example");
       setSize(500, 500);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Entry tmpEntry = new Entry();
       JPanel container = new JPanel();
       container.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
       container.setLayout(null);
       this.add(container);
       container.add(new Entry());
    }

}

class Entry extends JPanel{

    private int rotationAngle;

    public Entry(){
        this.setBounds(10,10, 200, 200);
        this.setSize(200,200);
        Entry me = this;
        rotationAngle = 0;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setOpaque(true);
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                rotationAngle += 10;
                me.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Path2D p = new Path2D.Float();
        p.moveTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() / 4);
        p.lineTo(getWidth()-(getWidth() / 4), getHeight() / 2);
        p.lineTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight()-(getHeight() / 4));
        p.closePath();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        g2d.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setBackground(null);

        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        g2d.fill(p);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Ty!

Axel

Comment: You may wish to delete comments that are no longer relevant. To clarify: What does your current do that you don't want it to do? What does it not do that you want it to do? Does making the JPanel non-opaque help? i.e., `setOpaque(false);` rather than true as you're currently doing.

Comment: What I want is the background to be transparent. I want a way of drawing the triangle and turn in on its center. The issue that I have with it is that if I don't clear the background, the old versions of the triangle stay (so if I turn 90 degrees and -90 I end up with both the 90 and -90 superimposed) but if I do I end up with an opaque background. Now, how stupid would I look if I say that yes `setOpaque(false);` does fix it... -_- I guess it didn't work in a test for something else I did. Mind to reply as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, set opaque on your drawing JPanel to false appears to fix your problem.

This was the program that I created several hours ago to test it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ClickNTurn extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            ClickNTurn ex = new ClickNTurn();
            ex.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public ClickNTurn() {

      setTitle("Simple example");
      setSize(500, 500);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Entry tmpEntry = new Entry();
      JPanel container = new JPanel();
      container.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
      container.setLayout(null);
      this.add(container);
      container.add(new Entry());
   }

}

class Entry extends JPanel {

   private int rotationAngle;

   public Entry() {
      this.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
      this.setSize(200, 200);
      // !! Entry me = this;
      rotationAngle = 0;
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      //!! setOpaque(true);
      setOpaque(false); //!!
      this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            rotationAngle += 10;
            // !! me.repaint();
            repaint();
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Path2D p = new Path2D.Float();
      p.moveTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() / 4);
      p.lineTo(getWidth() - (getWidth() / 4), getHeight() / 2);
      p.lineTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() - (getHeight() / 4));
      p.closePath();

      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      // g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

      //  g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g2d.setBackground(null);

      g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
      g2d.fill(p);
      g2d.dispose();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try setting the background color to "null"?

```
g2d.setBackground(null);
```

Comment: Neither 
`g2d.setBackground(null);
g2d.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());` nor `g2d.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));g2d.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());    g2d.setBackground(null);` work. The first one paints the whole thing green and the other one keeps the black background

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOpaque` and pass it `false`, this will make the component transparent, as well as let the paint engine know that it needs to take special care painting it, like clearing the `Graphics` context properly and painting beneath it.

There is nothing special you need to do in your code, simply continue painting as you normally would and the API will take care of the rest

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ClickNTurn extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClickNTurn ex = new ClickNTurn();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public ClickNTurn() {

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        add(new Entry());
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Entry extends JPanel {

        private int rotationAngle;

        public Entry() {
            Entry me = this;
            rotationAngle = 0;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    rotationAngle += 10;
                    me.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }



        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Path2D p = new Path2D.Float();
            p.moveTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() / 4);
            p.lineTo(getWidth() - (getWidth() / 4), getHeight() / 2);
            p.lineTo(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() - (getHeight() / 4));
            p.closePath();

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.fill(p);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```